# calculating odds overtime during the day

Tags: algorithm, math

I've a little problem to resolve and by going by trial and error i'm not being able to resolve it.

I have five variables:

```
a = 100
b = 7
c = 0
d = 24 * 60 * 60 // total seconds in one day
e = NN // seconds in the day so far, it's variable
```

I use this to reduce #a# (100) over time during the day, depending of #e#. That's pretty easy and it's currently done.

Now i need to introduce #b# and #c#; when #b# never changes; #c# does and can be 0 to 6, always staring from zero and increasing up to 7 over the day(its a random add at any time)

Here is where i struggle, so to explain myself a bit more:

Currently when: e = d/2 (halfway through day) the result will be: (a - 50).

With the changes, if #c# is zero the result should be the same (50 in my example).
But when #c# isn't zero => the result should be 50+someMagicNumber. Why? because #c# is closer tho reach the limit (#b#)

I'm not great at math, and also I'm writing this may help clear my mind :); if anyone understands what I'm trying to do and have any idea will appreciate; also excuse my English.

ps: once #c# reaches 7 the whole thing is done and this calculation isn't done. so #c# will always be < #b#

Comment: Perhaps you'd have more luck at http://math.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: What does "#c# is closer tho reach the limit" mean?

Comment: Should i re-post a new question there? (never used it)

Comment: @Kevin i means it has some value (not zero): like 3.

Comment: This description is kind of confusing. Maybe try to write is as pseudocode and continue from there?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the expression you're trying to evaluate is `a * (c + e/d)`.  You say that `a` and `d` are constants (cannot vary) and `c` and `e` are variables.  By the way, `d` is 86400 (the value of 24*60*60).

Let's just consider the cases where `c` is zero, first. If `c` is 0 and `e` is 0 then your result is 0. If `c` is 0 and `e` is 1, the result is 100/`d`, which is 1/864.  If `c` is 0 and `e` is 2, the result is 2/864, and so forth.  Each time we increase `e` by 1, the result increases by 1/864.

If `c` is 0 and `e` is `d - 1`, the result is 100 - 1/864.  This is the last second of the first day of your week.  For the next case, instead of setting `e == d`, you should say `c` is 1 and `e` is 0.  And your result should increase by 1/864 again, so the result is 100 exactly.

So by going from `c==0`, `e==0` to the case `c==1`, `e==0`, you increased your result by 100.  And each time you add 1 to `c` you will increase your result by 100 again.

Comment: Thanks David for your reasoning/explanations. Trying to understand it now and giving it a try.